# Jquery $.get cuts url after hashtag

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send an url with hashtags to the server, like

> /example.php?var1=tes#t&var2=value2

If i track the url in the beforeSend function I see that the url is only

> /example.php?var1=tes

And everything after the hashtag and inclusive hashtag was removed. If I encode the hashtag to %23 before i use the $.get() function everything works perfect.

Here is an example code.

```
    $.ajaxSetup(
    { 
        scriptCharset: "iso-8859-1",
        contentType: 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1',
        cache: true,

        //zuerst alles encodieren, damit server keine fehler bekommt
        beforeSend: function(xhr, data) 
        {
            //wrong url
            console.log(data.url);
        }
    });

    //right url
    var link = "/example.php?var1=tes#t&var2=value2";
    $.get(link).done(function()
    {
        console.log("done");
    })
```

**Edit:**

The server decode the url with iso-8859-1, so i need to encode the data to iso. I wrote an script in the beforeSend function whitch automatically convert the url to iso, but it can not convert the hashtag, because the data.url variable doesn't contain the hashtag. So i need to acces the full url (included the hashtag), in the $.ajaxSetup function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The characters after the # are being seen as a hash and not part of the querystring. You need to encode the special characters. You should use encodeURIComponent to do it.

But the nice thing is jQuery has the $.param() method built into the get method which will do the conversion for you.

```
var link = "/example.php";
$.get(link, { "var1" : "tes#t", "var2" : "value2" }). done(...);
```

Comment: The $.parm() method encodes with UTF-8, but I need iso.

Comment: I solved my problem. I use your answer and i wrote additional in the beforeSend method decodeURIComponent() to decode the UTF-8 encoded parameters. And then i use my script which converts the string to iso. And everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Apply [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to your URL string

Comment: This is a good idea, but encodeURIComponent() encodes my String to UTF-8 but the Server decode with iso. encodeURIComponent("ä") -> "%C3%A4". I can work with .replace to change the hash to the iso code, but then i must do this with hundreds of urls, and i try to wrote less code.

Comment: Assuming PHP from your code, use [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

Comment: The Server didn't use PHP. My code was only an example. Furthermore I haven't access to the server, so i need to solve this problem with Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The URL is invalid / malformed.

The hashtag **must be** the last part of the URL.

The hashtag **is not part** of the HTTP request and must therefore not be in there at all.

You cannot put the hashtag in the middle of the URL, there is only one pattern:

```
prot://domain/resource?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2#fragment_identifier
```

If the following won't work, it won't work at all:

```
/example.php?var1=test&var2=value2#hashval
```

> When a URI reference is used to perform a retrieval action on the
>   identified resource, the optional fragment identifier, separated from
>   the URI by a crosshatch (“#”) character, consists of additional
>   reference information to be interpreted by the user agent after the
>   retrieval action has been successfully completed. As such, it is not
>   part of a URI, but is often used in conjunction with a URI.

http://www.w3.org/blog/2011/05/hash-uris/

**Prove:** Requesting the URL - http://flowl.info/test#test

The fragment identifier (#) is not used during the HTTP request:

> [26/Sep/2014:14:11:10 +0000] "GET **/test** HTTP/1.1" 200 988 "-"                        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0"

**Another prove:**

Upload a PHP file containing `<?php phpinfo();` onto your server and access it with a `#fragment_identifier`... in the generated information, the hash value is not mentioned once. **Because for the server, it doesn't even exist.**

Answer (score 0):

As @luigi-belli proposed: apply encodeURIComponent()

Alternatively move your URL query parameters to have your call as such:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
        scriptCharset: "iso-8859-1",
        contentType: 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1',
        cache: true,
        data: { 'var1' : 'test#t', 'var2' : 'value2' }

        //zuerst alles encodieren, damit server keine fehler bekommt
        beforeSend: function(xhr, data) 
        {
            //wrong url
            console.log(data.url);
        }
    });

    //right url
    var link = "/example.php";
    $.get(link).done(function()
    {
        console.log("done");
    });
```

Comment: Why would you set data in Ajax setup?

Comment: @epascarello you are totally right. I was just copying the code from the question